# When website is loaded, get news from txt file

Tags: html, onload

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("body").ready(function() {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url : "helloworld.txt",
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    success : function (data) {
                                        $(".slider").html(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });</script>
```

I want this code to get `HTML` code from a `.txt` file and add it in here:

```
<div class="slider"> <!-- News Slider --> </div>
```

The txt file contains the following:

```
<div class="callbacks_container">
                            <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
                                <li>              
                                    <h2><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=news/christmas--zeah?oldschool=1">Zeah</a></h2>
                                    <h3><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=news/christmas--zeah?oldschool=1">New continent, 50% expansion</a></h3>
                                </li>
                                <li>              
                                    <h2><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Sailing</a></h2>
                                    <h3><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Sail around the world</a></h3>
                                </li>
                                <li>              
                                    <h2><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=news/old-school-in-2016?oldschool=1">2016</a></h2>     
                                    <h3><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=news/old-school-in-2016?oldschool=1">Christmas event coming to an end</a></h3>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

The function above doesn't work and I can't find a way to fix this.

Comment: What exactly does not work? What error does the console throw? Since your text file seems to hold html, why not use a `.html` file and datatype: `'html'`?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a few braces at the end and the URL should be /helloworld.txt

The / is importamt
I suggest using syntax highlighting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/helloworld.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            console.log("executed");
            $(".slider").html(data);
        }
    });
})})
</script>
```